# Haskell - About Curried

Tags: haskell

In Haskell all functions are originally curried, right?

So, let's look at the `max` function, and I'll write what I understand about how this works.

When I write something like this:

```
max 4 5
```

What happens is that a new funcion is created that internally has value of 4, which then recieves a value, so this function is applied to 5 and a correct value is returned?

Did I say something wrong somehow or is this correct?

Comment: Remember folks: justify your downvotes in the comments.

Comment: I'm guessing they're due to the question having grammatical errors, which is not a good reason to downvote... if the question is hard to understand, ask for clarification.

Comment: You can't downvote for missing knowledge on a Q&A site, but you can for lack of effort, however I think the question shows good understanding, and clear (successful) effort to resolve the issue. I've corrected some of the grammar to subject-verb-object, because object-verb-subject was obsuring the meaning somewhat.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's correct.  You can remember what currying is all about by memorizing two of its most important identities:

```
-- Function type right-associativity:
a -> b -> c = a -> (b -> c)

-- Function application left-associativity:
f x y = (f x) y
```

These two identities work together and produce a curried language.

Comment: @user428691 So `max 4 5` is short for `(max 4) 5` and `max 4 :: Integer -> Integer` which means it's a function, just like you said.